# history of changes to a column

Tags: sql, datetime

Please, consider the following scenario.
There are 2 tables: Core and History. Core looks as follows

---

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HWDateStart | HWDateEnd | HWQueueID |
| 2022-05-29 10:00:00 | 2022-06-04 00:45:00 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-01 |
| 2022-05-29 10:00:00 | 2022-06-04 00:45:00 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-02 |

History looks as follows

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cntDatetime | cntSerialNumber | cntQueueName | cntQueueID |
| 2022-05-29 02:28:00 | SN01-01 | p00-0000-01 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-01 |
| 2022-05-29 02:28:00 | SN02-01 | p00-0000-02 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-02 |
| 2022-06-04 00:26:00 | SN02-02 | p00-0000-02 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-02 |
| 2022-06-04 00:26:00 | SN01-01 | p00-0000-01 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-01 |

History holds a list of cntSerialNumber changes through the time
The following script that gives the user SerialNumber as it was at the beginning and the end of a certain period

```
    SELECT Convert(date,[HWDateStart]) 
      ,Convert(date,[HWDateEnd]) 
      ,[HWQueueID]
      , HS.cntSerialNumber
      , HE.cntSerialNumber
  FROM [watchdocstats].[dbo].[tblJT] SNTarget,
  [watchdocstats].[dbo].[tblQueueByConfig] HS,
  [watchdocstats].[dbo].[tblQueueByConfig] HE
    WHERE 
        SNTarget.HWQueueID      = HS.cntQueueID
  AND   SNTarget.HWQueueID      = HE.cntQueueID
  AND   Convert(date,SNTarget.HWDateStart) = Convert(date,HS.cntDatetime)
  AND   Convert(date,SNTarget.HWDateEnd) = Convert(date,HE.cntDatetime)
```

But what if SerialNumber has been changed more than once down the road
Is there a way to select a table that would show commaseparated SerialNumbers in cntSerialNumber column?
Smth, like

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Start) | (End) | HWQueueID | cntSNHist |
| 2022-05-29 | 2022-06-04 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-01 | SN01-01 |
| 2022-05-29 | 2022-06-04 | WIN-S671INNTGRE.P00-K0-02 | SN02-01,SN02-02,SN02-03 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your DBMS, you should be able to use the LISTAGG function along with a GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thank you, NickW! I'll try you suggestion on MSSQL